# Using Regex Operators in Python/Pandas to Count Data Entries Conditionally

Tags: python, regex, pandas, logical-operators

Using the pandas library in Python, I have a device in my code that looks like this:

```
BadData = len(df[df.A1.str.contains('A|T|C|G')==False])
```

What I'm trying to do here is count the number of entries in the `A1` column of the dataframe `df` that *do not* contain any combination of the letters A, T, C, and G.

These expressions should be counted as `BadData`:

- 123
- <%*&
- foo

But these expressions should not:

- A
- ATCG
- GATCATTA

**My question**: how could I use regex characters to include entries like "**A**pple" or "**G**olfing" in `BadData`?

I could chain together conditions like so:

```
BadData = len(df[(df.A1.str.contains('A|T|C|G')==False) & (df.A1.str.contains('0|1|2|3')==TRUE)])
```

But here I face a difficulty: do I have to define every character that violates the condition? This seems clumsy, and I am sure there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['A1'].str.contains('^[ACTG]+$')
```

Which makes sure that it both starts (the regex `^`) and ends (the regex `$`) with a letter in `ACTG`, and only contains one or more of those characters.

To get the `len`, you can just sum the `False` values:

```
bad_data = sum(~df['A1'].str.contains('^[ACTG]+$'))
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
bad_data = len(df[df.A1.str.contains('^[ACTG]+$')==False])
```

But IMO nicer to read.

**For example:**

```
>>> df
             A1
0         Apple
1       Golfing
2             A
3          ATTC
4          ACGT
5         AxTCG
6           foo
7             %
8  ACT Golf GTC
9           ACT


>>> df['A1'].str.contains('^[ACTG]+$')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: A1, dtype: bool

bad_data = sum(~df['A1'].str.contains('^[ACTG]+$'))
# 6
```

Comment: Elegant and straightforward solution. Thank you! :)